# ESPHome Cover lambda-function

Tags: lambda, home-assistant, esphome

I'm trying to control my cover with 2 buttons in ESP-Home.

When i click on it short, it should either stop or start (close/open) the cover.

But inside of the lambda, it always jumps into the stop-function. Even if the cover is not moving. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 binary_sensor:
  - platform: gpio
    internal: True
    pin:
      number: D1
      inverted: true
      mode:
        input: true
        pullup: true
    name: "Taster UP"
    on_click:
      min_length: 0ms
      max_length: 350ms
      then:
        - lambda: |-
            if((id(template_cover).current_operation == COVER_OPERATION_CLOSING)||(id(template_cover).current_operation == COVER_OPERATION_OPENING))
            {
              auto call1 = id(template_cover).make_call();
              call1.set_command_stop();
              call1.perform();
            }
            else
            {
              auto call1 = id(template_cover).make_call();
              call1.set_command_open();
              call1.perform();
            }
    on_press:
      then:
        - cover.open: template_cover
    on_release:
      then:
        - cover.stop: template_cover
```